# How to create an android library than can be used only in debug mode?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

This is my situation. I want to create an android artifact to be used in other projects. But, I want this library to be used only for debugging purposes. I think in just import the library like this

```
debugImplementation "com.example.android.debugin_library:1.0.0"
```

But I want to have more control and avoid that somebody else at some point adds this library in release mode. I was thinking if It's possible to launch a compile-time error if somebody does something like this:

```
Implementation:"com.example.android.debugin_library:1.0.0"
releaseImplementation:"com.example.android.debugin_library:1.0.0"
```

Any idea will be great! Thanks! :D